# How to access data outside the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my **`component.ts`**

```
export class OrganizationsComponent {

  public organizations;

  constructor(public access: OrganizationService) {

    this.access.getOrganizations().subscribe((data => {
      this.organizations = data;
      console.log(this.organizations);
    }))
   console.log(this.organizations)
}
```

How do I get data outside the constructor?

Comment: Please add more description in your question.

Comment: [**Reserve the constructor for simple initialization such as wiring constructor parameters to properties. The constructor shouldn't do anything. It certainly shouldn't call a function that makes HTTP requests to a remote server as a real data service would.**](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: What are you getting in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, You can do like this

```
constructor(public access: OrganizationService) {}

get(){
    this.access.getOrganizations().subscribe((data => {
      this.organizations = data;
      console.log(this.organizations);
    }))
   console.log(this.organizations)
}

ngOninit(){
  this.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you cannot access the `organizations` property outside of the subscribe block, because of JavaScript/TypeScript's asynchronous properties. You may read more about the Event Loop over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), as it provides a more detailed explanation. Therefore, you will need to use `.subscribe()` to return the observable value.

The problem with

```
this.access.getOrganizations().subscribe((data => {
  this.organizations = data;
}));
console.log(this.organizations);
```

is that `console.log(this.organizations);` will finish executing before the subscription is completed, hence it will print a value of `undefined`. The correct way of printing `organizations` is to do this instead:

```
this.access.getOrganizations().subscribe((data => {
  this.organizations = data;
  console.log(this.organizations);
}));
```

In addition, as explained on the comments, you should not be returning the observable on the constructor. I recommend you to return it on the [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) life cycle instead.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.access.getOrganizations().subscribe((data => {
    this.organizations = data;
    console.log(this.organizations);
  }));
}
```

Alternatively, you may store it as an observable instead, and return it later when you really need it.

```
organizations: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.organizations = this.access.getOrganizations();
}

someOthermethod() {
  this.organizations.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **First of all, you should not call the service inside the constructor**
>
> [**Reserve the constructor for simple initialization such as wiring
>   constructor parameters to properties. The constructor shouldn't do
>   anything. It certainly shouldn't call a function that makes HTTP
>   requests to a remote server as a real data service
>   would.**](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

**You should modify your `OrganisationsComponent` to something like below:~**

```
export class OrganisationsComponent {

  dataFromServer: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private access: OrganizationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.access.getOrganizations().subscribe((data => {
      this.organizations = data;
      console.log(this.organizations);
    }));
    // console.log(this.organizations); // undefined because by the time subscribe is called you are console logging it
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.organizations); },5000);
  } 
}
```

> **Explanation:~**
>
> **You will not get the data outside the subscribe block because it's**
>   **async, you don't have value there!**
>
> or
>
> **precisely undefined -> 'getOrganizations()' hadn't returned Observable**
>   **by the time it's logging to console.**
>
> **So, based on your service call response time you can test in**
>   **setTimeout**.

A simple example with your problem here [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-service-demo-in-angular-guj1yn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Hope this helps !**

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the observable into the promise and await it so when the promise will be resolved the value will be accessible.

```
export class OrganizationsComponent {

    public organizations;

    constructor(public access: OrganizationService) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
        this.organizations = await this.access.getOrganizations()
          .pipe(first())
          .toPromise();
        console.log("Organization Name: ", this.organizations[0].name)
    }

}
```